# dplyr: Add variable as function of all variables in each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a new variable in a dataframe using `dplyr` but I find it difficult.

The new variable should be the number of runs with length 2 (of all the variable values in each line). Using `apply` I would do this:

```
tmp$rle = apply(tmp,1,function(x) sum(rle(x)$lengths==2))
```

How can I perform this action using `dplyr` and `mutate` (without defining all variable names) ?

```
tmp <- structure(list(X1 = c(3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2), X2 = c(2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), X3 = c(2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2), X4 = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), X5 = c(4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3), X6 = c(3, 1, 4, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3), X7 = c(4, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4), X8 = c(1, 
3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `dplyr`, you might consider using the `purrr` package which RStudio has fairly recently introduced as a complement to `dplyr` to, among other things, better handle vectors and lists.   In your case, `tmp` is a numeric data frame where you want to treat each row as a vector.  The code could look like:

```
library(purrr)
tmp <- tmp %>% by_row(..f=function(x) sum(rle(x)$lengths==2), 
                      .to = "rle", .collate = "cols")
```

Answer (score 1):

In dplyr:

```
tmp <- mutate(tmp, rle = apply(tmp, 1, function(x) sum(rle(x)$lengths==2)))
```

I am having a difficult time QA'ing this as I am unfamiliar with what results I should expect out of the rle function. I tried comparing results with your apply version of the code, and it seems that set.seed() is perhaps important for replicability? Am I understanding this correctly?

Here is the QA attempt I made: (original *tmp* should be exactly the same: I just wrapped the lines at the `list()` and `structure()` arguments.)

```
set.seed(1)
tmp <- structure(list(X1 = c(3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2),
                      X2 = c(2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1),
                      X3 = c(2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2),
                      X4 = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1),
                      X5 = c(4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3),
                      X6 = c(3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3),
                      X7 = c(4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4),
                      X8 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4)),
                 .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
tmpApply <- tmp
tmpApply$rle = apply(tmp, 1, function(x) sum(rle(x)$lengths==2))
tmpDplyr <- tmp %>% mutate(rle = apply(tmp, 1, function(x) sum(rle(x)$lengths==2))) 

tmpApply            
tmpDplyr
```

Comment: NB: successfully getting an `apply` to work inside a `mutate` call in dplyr is a rare occurance for me. I would love to learn why it is so difficult to make this happen....